# pandas: slice on hierarchical index without a copy

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I would like to modify DataFrame entries for some rows at a specific level of a hierarchical index. Here is a canonical example:

```
>>> index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['a','a', 'b', 'b'], [1,2,1,2]], 
...                                   names=['first', 'second'])
>>> data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index)), index=index, columns=['A'])
>>> print data
                     A
first second          
a     1       0.587781
      2       0.560407
b     1       0.492996
      2       0.267799
```

I would like to set rows for which `second==2` to 0 (for example). I tried using `DataFrame.xs` method but it returns a copy and not a view:

```
>>> selected = data.xs(2, level='second')
>>> print selected
              A
first          
a      0.560407
b      0.267799

>>> selected['A']=0
>>> print data

                    A
first second          
a     1       0.587781
      2       0.560407
b     1       0.492996
      2       0.267799
```

The last assignment did not affect `data` (it changed values in `selected` of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In recent version of pandas `help(data.xs)` shows how to get a view on the data.

It can be done by using `xs arg copy=False`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It seems to work fine with single-level index, but it does not work with multi-index. My pandas version is 0.9.0

Comment: Seems to be a problem, i opened an issue for it https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2117

Comment: Thanks for reporting. Is there any work around I could apply before it is fixed?

Comment: Slicing works fine, but you need to construct the slice manually knowing the structure of the table. In the above example: data[1::2]['A']=0

Comment: Or use a boolean mask: data.A[data.index.get_level_values(1) == 2] = 0